# Best way to model aging in an animal

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to model aging in an animal population. The first thing I tried was this:

```
if (rand() > 1 - 1/lifespan) { die(); }
```

This (of course) gave me an exponential distribution, so I realized I needed something better. So I tried this:

```
if (rand() > 1 - age/(lifespan*lifespan)) { die(); }
```

Which is better. The "top" of the distribution is at `lifespan`. However looking at the distribution it still doesn't look like a great model for aging, and I'm already out of my depth when it comes to statistics here. So my question is; is there a way to modify the code above to make it a decent model of aging?

Comment: You may want a more complicated function than `1/lifespan` or `age/(lifespan*lifespan)` as the probability of dying in a given year. There is a lot of information about what it ought to look like for humans. See, for instance, [this page](http://www.bandolier.org.uk/booth/Risk/dyingage.html), or any other search result for "probability of dying by age". Try to model something like that, and your lifespan distribution will be more realistic. You can also tweak yourself wether you want, say, infant mortality to be high or low, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like that is following `rand() > 1 - A*exp(B*age)` (when age > 5), where for humans A=1/15000 and B=0.08. However I'm not sure exactly how to think about the A and B constants? If anyone knows a way to intuitively think about these (and thereby how to tweak them) I'd be grateful!